# Advantage of typed Get in httpclient

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

Can anyone explain the advantage of a typed get method in httpClient in angular 5.
Specifically the difference between   `get(url..);`  and  `get<myObject>(url)`.

What I have understood is that the second method is used to specify the type of data we are getting back. But if the backend api returns a json object, is this needed ?
The Backend api returns a jsonObject in my case. So is there any specific advantage if I specify the second `get<myObject>`.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `get(url)`, you get back an `Observable<Object>`, which doesn't tell much about what your service method actually returns, and thus forces every caller of the service to guess, and to use a type assertion to tell TypeScript: trust me, this object is in fact a User, or a Task, or whatever your service actually returns.

If you call `get<User>(url)`, you get back an `Observable<User>`, which precisely tells what the service returns, and doesn't force all the callers to guess, and frees them from using any type assertion, since you did it already, once, in the service.